# Responsive auto height container after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I change height of my element via javascript (couldn't change it via css from 0 to auto).

```
/* Function to animate height: auto */
function autoHeightAnimate(element, time){
    var curHeight = element.height(), // Get Default Height
        autoHeight = element.css('height', 'auto').height(); // Get Auto Height
          element.height(curHeight); // Reset to Default Height
          element.stop().animate({ height: autoHeight }, time); // Animate to Auto Height
}
```

After I resize my Chrome window the element doesn't automatically change its height, because it only changes after I click one of labels.
[DEMO](http://codepen.io/fritris/pen/XKGmbv) here.

Is possible to do it somehow via css? And if not how to do it via javascript/jQuery to make it changes after I scale my browser window?

Comment: why are you setting it to a fixed height, just make it to `auto` when expanded and `zero` while collapsed.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay I do? I tought `autoHeight = element.css('height', 'auto').height(); ` makes it auto.

Answer (score 0):

In this cases you can use from resize function and set height when resize happened like this:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
      autoHeightAnimate('','');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. I still think it's stupid you can't do it by css tranform, but I guess that's the way. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome, your up vote can help to others to see one of correct answer